# Python: Pyro: OpenOPC: Connection failed

Tags: uri, opc, pyro

I'm trying to set up OpenOPC for Python in combination with Pyro.
Whenever I try to connect to the OPC server I get this error:

> Pyro.errors.ProtocolError: connection failed

I looked this up and it seems that Pyro is binding the server on the loopback adapter (making it invisible from the outside).

What I have tried so far:

Edit the etc/hosts file:

```
Changed: 
127.0.0.1         localhost  
into 
192.168.4.93      localhost
```

This didn't work.

Edit configuration.py from Pyro:

```
Changed:
'PYRO_HOST':            '',
'PYRO_PUBLISHHOST':     None,
'PYRO_NS_HOSTNAME':     None,
into
'PYRO_HOST':            '192.168.4.93',
'PYRO_PUBLISHHOST':     '192.168.4.93',
'PYRO_NS_HOSTNAME':     '192.168.4.93',
```

This didn't work either. Also after rebooting/restarting the Pyro nameserver.

Does anyone have any idea what else I could try to get it working?
I also ran the OpenOPC client on my windows computer (same one as the OPC server) and this worked. I use the same version of Pyro on my Windows computer and Ubuntu computer.

Edit:
I have also changed OpenOPCService.py:

```
opc_gate_host = None 
into 
opc_gate_host = '192.168.4.93'
```

This doesn't work either...

Could anyone please help? I'm working on this now for over a day without any succes so far...

Comment: Using the Matrikon Explorer tool, are you able to see and connect to your remote OPC server? The OPC server is DA and is running on a Windows box right?

Comment: I don't know how I exactly fixed it but I got it working now somehow...
I THINK, in the end, only etc/hosts had to be adjusted. I don't know why it didn't work before.